# Custom deeplinking scheme doesn't work in some cases

Tags: android, intentfilter, deep-linking

Custom deeplinking scheme doesn't work in case other data tag is added to intent-filter.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="@string/deep_link_scheme" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myhost" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myhost" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Moving custom theme data tag to separate intent-filter fixes the problem, but what the real problem with the first solution?

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myhost" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myhost" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="@string/deep_link_scheme" />
    </intent-filter>
```